# Can't pass an enumerable model to a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm a bit confused because I thought this a very straight-forward thing, it's possibly something simple tripping me up.

I have a view:

```
@model IEnumerable<CarViewModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SummarySaveAll", "VroomVroom", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="1">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Driver)
                </th>
                <th width="1">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Colour.Name)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (var element in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td width="1">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => element.Driver)
                    </td>
                    <td width="1">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => element.Colour, element.Colours, "Unknown")
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn" />
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel Changes", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn" })
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

and the list/enumerable of `CarViewModel` is supposed to bounce back to the `VroomVroom` controller, action `SummarySaveAll` which it does - but the viewmodel on the page doesn't get passed back to it:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SummarySaveAll(IEnumerable<CarViewModel> summaries)
    {
        // Want to do stuff with summaries but it's always null
        return View();
    }
```

I tried to encapsulate the List in another ViewModel and cycle through elements using a `for i` loop but that wouldn't pass back to the controller either.

**Surely it's possible to send a List or IEnumerable of models back to a controller?**

My CarVM:

```
public class CarViewModel
{
    [MaxLength(150)]
    [Display(AutoGenerateField = true, Name = "Entered By")]
    public string Driver { get; set; }

    [Display(AutoGenerateField = true)]
    public Colour Colour { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Colours { get; set; }

    public CarViewModel() { }

    public CarViewModel(Model CarModel summaryModel, CarPropertyCollection propertyCollection)
    {
        Driver = summaryModel.Driver;
        Id = summaryModel.Id;
        IsDeleted = summaryModel.IsDeleted;

        Colour = summaryModel.Colour == null ? null :
            propertyCollection.Colours.Where(x => x.Id == summaryModel.Colour.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        Colours = propertyCollection.Colours.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.Name });

    }
}
```

}

Must stress that `Colour` is a custom class but only has Id and Name properties

Comment: You can only bind to an indexable collection e.g. `IList<T>`. You will also need to use a `for` loop in your view, so the inputs are named with an index.

Comment: I swear I had tried that first, because of something I read ages ago. I'm going to try again and see how it goes.

Comment: Oh yeah, the reason I didn't go that way is because my dropDownList needed a set of SelectListItems and the only way I could pass that through was if I wrapped the list up in a VM and the encapsulated indexed list didn't bind either! I'm going to have to add the SelectListItems to each instance of the ViewModel

Comment: And now I have only the id's being passed back to the controller ehhhhh

Comment: Can you post your `CarViewModel`?

Comment: Posted - please bear in mind the associated `Colour` class is a custom class and not the .Net Colour class

Comment: I've indexed the list using a `for i` loop and I've added a `hiddenfor` for the id at the top of the <tr> - everything still shows well on the view but it's only passing the id back to the controller. If I change `DisplayFor` to `EditorFor` it still doesn't send anything back. Confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Colours` doesn't relate to a specific car, it relates to cars in general, so rather than using a collection as your view model, create a wrapper:

```
class EditCarsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Colours { get; set; }

    public IList<CarViewModel> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Then your view:

```
@model EditCarsViewModel

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Cars.Length; i++)
{
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Cars[i].Colour, Model.Colours, "Unknown")
    </td>
}
```

Any other `CarViewModel` properties will need their own input as well. `HiddenFor` can be used if they should be readonly:

```
@model EditCarsViewModel

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Cars.Length; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Cars[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Cars[i].Driver)
    <!-- etc. -->
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Cars[i].Colour.Id, Model.Colours, "Unknown")
    </td>
}
```

And your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SummarySaveAll(EditCarViewModel model)
{
    // model.Cars should be populated
    return View();
}
```

Note that an indexable collection, such as `IList<T>` should be used, as the form field names need to include the index to differentiate the items.

**Edit by OP**
The `Colour` class consists of a `[Key] int Id` property and a `string Name` property. For `DropDownList` items I had to make sure the `Id` property was specified on the `m => Model.Cars[i].Colour.Id` line otherwise that particular prop was coming back as null even though other items were coming through fine.

Comment: This was my setup at the start, or at least a very close approximation! I had the list inside a VM to contain those generic properties and a conditional displaymessage. If I redo it like this and it works I'm going to be both very happy and totally distraught at the same time :D

Comment: Ok, so I went back to this setup and experimented - the absolute key to this was making sure I had the `Id` property selected for the dropDownList so `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Cars[i].Colour, Model.Colours, "Unknown")` should be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Cars[i].Colour.Id, Model.Colours, "Unknown")` - if I just use `Colour` I get `null` and if I used the `Name` property of my `Colour` model then the `Name` was becoming the #`Id`. In a nutshell, I was three characters away in my original setup and just spent 2 hours undoing and redoing it! FFS! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah yes, `Colour` is a reference type so it can't be edited directly via a select list; I didn't spot that.

Comment: Yup, makes sense. The really annoying thing is I've got the same working setup for individual car items and I have the `.Id` prop there as usual... I just missed it the first time round. Coding is super fun!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SummarySaveAll(IList<CarViewModel> summaries)
{
    // Want to do stuff with summaries but it's always null
    return View(summaries);
}
```

I've also added this model as a param for your view

Comment: Doesn't work unless I index the list so I'll have to change the view also

Answer (score 1):

This how you do it:

First my View which posts back to a controller named Home and an action named ListView:

```
@model List<MyModel>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Using a list as model";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ListView", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="1">
                    Name
                </th>
                <th width="1">
                    Description
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td width="1">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Name)
                    </td>
                    <td width="1">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Description)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn" />
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel Changes", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn" })
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

Notice how I used an indexer to render the controls **[i]**

This is my model:

```
  public class MyModel
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
  }
```

This is my controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ListView(IEnumerable<MyModel> model)
{

  return View(model);
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]